# How to get a Binding content in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, data-binding, binding, chat

this is my code:

```
public ChatItemCell()
    {
        TextAlignment Ausrichtung = TextAlignment.Start;

        var lblBody = new Label()
        {
            FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Medium, typeof(Label)), 
            HorizontalTextAlignment = Ausrichtung,
            TextColor = Color.Black
        };
        lblBody.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Body");

        var lblSender = new Label()
        {
            FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Small, typeof(Label)),
            HorizontalTextAlignment = Ausrichtung,
            TextColor = Color.Gray,
            FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Italic
        };
        lblSender.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Sender");

        var layout = new StackLayout()
        {
            Opacity = 90,
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
            Children = {lblSender, lblBody}
        };

        Frame outerFrame = new Frame()
        {
            Padding = new Thickness(5, 5, 5, 5),
            OutlineColor = Color.Accent,
            BackgroundColor = Color.Yellow,
            Content = layout,
        };

        Frame objFrame_Outer = new Frame
        {
            Padding = new Thickness(10, 0, 10, 10),
            Content = outerFrame
        };

        View = objFrame_Outer;

    }
```

What I want is, that the TextAligment depends on the "Sender". Means: When the Sender is "me" the aligment should be left, otherwise it should be right. So how do I get the content of "Sender"?

Thanks a lot!
Kriz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind the TextAlignment property of the label to the Sender property, and write a ValueConverter that returns the correct TextAlignment for the value of Sender:

```
public class TextAlignmentConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var s = value as string;
        if (s == null) return TextAlignment.End;
        if (s.ToLower() == "me")
            return TextAlignment.Start;
        return TextAlignment.End;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But is there another way? I can remember that there was a way to get access to a binding like Bindingcontext.("Sender"), but I cannot find it... Because I also  need to get the length of the "body" to fit the width of the viewcell..

Comment: Hey TommyHaugland, could you give me a hint how to use this converter?

Comment: I very rarely construct my UI elements in code behind, but I think this should work: `lblSender.SetBinding(Label.TextAlignmentProperty, new Binding("Sender", BindingMode.Default,
        new TextAlignmentConverter(), null));`